# How can convert this sql query into django queryset

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

These are My models:
These are my models:

```
class CreditPaymentDetail(models.Model):
    bill_master = models.ForeignKey(BillMaster, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0.0,
                                           help_text="max_value upto 9999999.99")
```

```
class BillMaster(models.Model):
    PAY_TYPE = (
        (0 , "CASH"),
        (1 , "CREDIT")
    )
    BILL_TYPE = (
        (0 , "INVOICE"),
        (1 , "REFUND")
    )
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer,on_delete= models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    pay_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=PAY_TYPE, default=0, help_text= "Where 0 = CASH, 1 = CREDIT")
    grand_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, default=0.0, help_text="Grand total")
```

```
class Customer(NowTimestampAndUserModel):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

This is DjangoQuery i have tried:

```
bills = BillMaster.objects.filter(pay_type=1, customer=2).values('order_id', 'customer_id', 'invoice_no', 'grand_total').annotate(paid_amount=Coalesce(Sum('creditpaymentdetail__amount'), 0))
bills = bills.values('customer_id').annotate(gt=Coalesce(Sum('grand_total'), 0))
```

which is equivalent to postgreSQL query :

```
SELECT "bill_billmaster"."customer_id",
COALESCE(SUM("bill_billmaster"."grand_total"), 0) AS "gt" FROM "bill_billmaster" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "credit_management_creditpaymentdetail" 
ON ("bill_billmaster"."id" = "credit_management_creditpaymentdetail"."bill_master_id") 
WHERE "bill_billmaster"."pay_type" = 1 
GROUP BY "bill_billmaster"."customer_id"
```

But I want to achieve this postgreSQL query:

```
select customer_id, sum(gt) gt from (
SELECT "bill_billmaster"."customer_id", 
"bill_billmaster"."grand_total" AS "gt" FROM "bill_billmaster" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "credit_management_creditpaymentdetail" 
ON ("bill_billmaster"."id" = "credit_management_creditpaymentdetail"."bill_master_id") 
WHERE "bill_billmaster"."pay_type" = 1 
GROUP BY "bill_billmaster"."customer_id", grand_total
    ) R group by customer_id
```

I want to get data with customer_id ,sum of CREDIT of all bill_master__grand_total of that customer, sum of credit_payment_detail__amount of that customer and due amount like i have succeed to retrieve:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clNOK.png)
i want to retrieve data like
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8bug.png)

Comment: I am not good at sql queries (feeling bad) but I know django ORM. If you explain what you need, I will try to help

Comment: check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: please share your models.